# JSON response format is incorrect(Swift)

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am new to Swift and I am getting response from mysql through PHP script in JSON format. But my JSON is in correct format :

```
    ["Result": <__NSArrayI 0x60000005bc60>(
<__NSArray0 0x608000000610>(

)
,

{
    name = "abc" ;
    address = "abc address"

},
{
    name = "xyz" ;
    address = "xyz address"

}
)
]
```

my code for serialisation is :

```
let url = URL(string: "my url")

    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let body = "Id=\(Id)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)
   // request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if error == nil {

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                do {
                    if let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? Dictionary<String,Any>{

                        print(json)
```

Where am I going wrong?

**POSTMAN output**

```
{
"Result": [
    {
        name = "abc" ;
        address = "abc address"
    },
    {
        name = "xyz" ;
        address = "xyz address"
    }

]
```

}

Comment: The problem is you are casting array as `Dictionary<String,Any>`? Try change it to `as? [Any]`

Comment: Can you please share the request link and param with me? So that it will be easier to test. @swiftuser123

Comment: @Tj3n I did changed to ' as? [Any]' Still its in same wrong format.

Comment: @emraz I have mentioned request link and param I did mentioned in my question.

Comment: You can just remove the `as?` and print it to see its format

Comment: I think the response you are getting from server is not in well format, If possible share the actual link and param with me. Or you can test using POSTMAN, so that you can easily check the actual response of your POST link.

Comment: Dude. You're confusing the JSON syntax with the PLIST syntax. When you print `json` it is *not typed* so print shows a PLIST format of the JSON. *But this is the same content.* Once you cast `json` to the proper type, `[String: Any]`, print it then you will see something else. Then get "result" as `[[String: Any]]` (since it's an array of dictionaries) and print, you will see yet a different result. *Don't believe what you see when you print: believe what you debug, the real values*.

Comment: @EricAya You are Absolutely correct. I was simply getting stressed. You saved me. Thanks you !

Comment: @swiftuser123 Aaah cool, I'm super happy you got this. You're welcome. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it once.

```
let json = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**
Try this code..

//declare parameter as a dictionary

```
let parameters = ["Id": Id"] as Dictionary<String, String>

//url
let url = URL(string: "http://test.com/api")!

//session object
let session = URLSession.shared

//URLRequest object using the url object
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)

} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

    guard error == nil else {
        return
    }

    guard let data = data else {
        return
    }

    do {
        //json object from data
        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] {
            print(json)
            // handle json...
        }

    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
})
task.resume()
```

**Alamofire**

Try this code using Alamofire..

```
let parameters = [
    "name": "user1"]

let url = "https://myurl.com/api"
Alamofire.request(url, method:.post, parameters:parameters,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
               print(response)
            case .failure(let error):
                failure(0,"Error")
            }
        }
```

Comment: It sends empty json . ["Result": <__NSArrayM 0x600000253dd0>(
<__NSArrayM 0x600000253da0>(

)

)
]

Comment: I think the response you are getting from server is not in well format, If possible share the actual link and param with me. Or you can test using POSTMAN, so that you can easily check the actual response of your POST link.

Comment: Please send the output of POSTMAN response

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you get the response as json. Some times get string as response. If you get string then convert that json string to json object.
Check it is a valid json object

```
let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonOBJ) // jsonOBJ is the response from server

print(valid) // if true then it is a valid json object
```